# Seeking a sci-fi movie with a laser pistol and an amulet

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I'm looking for a movie (Circa early 80s, maybe late 70s) about a teenager who finds a laser pistol and succumbs to "Power corrupts" eventually going on a killing spree. I remember that the gun required an amulet than eventually began to change the teen. I think the teen was one of those kids that was made fun of and thus used the gun for retribution. I also remember the film not being very good so I've not had a lot of luck with Google on this one.

Comment: The "nerd looking for revenge after powers" and "bad movie" points me towards Toxic Avenger, but I don't recall lazers in that movie.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like [*Laserblast* (1978)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laserblast):

> "... Billy wanders into the desert and discovers the laser cannon and pendant. He starts playing with the cannon, pretending to shoot things, then realizes he can fire the weapon while wearing the pendant..."

An edited version was shown on MST3K.

Comment: Sadly after looking at that wikipedia entry that would seem to be the film. Further, after reading the entry; I'm vaguely ashamed for ever having seen it or asking about it on SE.

Comment: I'm equally guilty, I saw the thing and remembered it well enough to answer. On the positive side, I think that's the first time I've even been credited with answering a question on StackExchange.

Comment: Wow, good digging, Michael. I had a look through IMDb and got nothing... +1

Comment: +1 - Very good digging.  A question and answer about a movie in the bottom 100 of the IMDB - lol.